# How to create a table that should only allow a single relation to exist out of many?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table called `Configuration`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Configuration" 
(
    "id" CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    "namespace" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "value" JSONB NOT NULL,
    "level" "ConfigLevel" NOT NULL,
    "userId" CHAR(36),
    "orgId" CHAR(36),
    "teamId" CHAR(36),
    "moduleId" CHAR(36),
    "moduleSubscriptionId" CHAR(36),
    "workflowId" CHAR(36),
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Configuration_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

That also has a unique index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Configuration_namespace_key_level_userId_orgId_teamId_modul_key" 
ON "Configuration"("namespace", "key", "level", "userId", "orgId", "teamId", "moduleId", "moduleSubscriptionId", "workflowId");
```

My goal with this is to be able to save configurations for a given `namespace`, `key` and `level` **and** one of the possible relations (user, org, team, module, subscription or workflow).

I'm not happy with this setup though as if I add a new relation I need to modify the constraint and I also have to add individual fields for each relation (so all the others are always `NULL`).

Is there a database design pattern that I can apply here to make this easier to maintain and more forward-compatible?

Comment: Since you say your configuration links to one user type, you can have one user type id column and a user type column.

Comment: Which column stores the relation? Also, please add a few rows of sample data, and specify which cases are valid and which ones are not.

Comment: all the `*Id` columns store individual relations, so `"userId", "orgId", "teamId", "moduleId", "moduleSubscriptionId", "workflowId"`. The only valid case is when only one of these fields *is not null*.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern for DB subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism.

Comment: So what's the best practice then?

Answer (score 3):

Postgres provides functions [num_nulls() and num_nonnulls()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE). Add a `check constraint` on the number of those columns that must/cannot be null.

```
CREATE TABLE "Configuration" 
(
    "id" CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    "namespace" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "value" JSONB NOT NULL,
    "level" "ConfigLevel" NOT NULL,
    "userId" CHAR(36),
    "orgId" CHAR(36),
    "teamId" CHAR(36),
    "moduleId" CHAR(36),
    "moduleSubscriptionId" CHAR(36),
    "workflowId" CHAR(36),
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Configuration_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  , constraint just_one_value_ck check( num_nulls("userId"  
                                                 ,"orgId"  
                                                 ,"teamId"  
                                                 ,"moduleId"
                                                 ) = 1
                                      )  
);
```

You would be much better off using VARCHAR or TEXT instead of CHAR data type. See [Don't Do This:Text Storage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Text_storage)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, only a single column will be used for your relations

if my understanding is correct, then a design with a single column for all the possible relations would be better

```
CREATE TABLE "Configuration" 
(
    "id" CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    "namespace" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "key" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "value" JSONB NOT NULL,
    "level" "ConfigLevel" NOT NULL,
    "RelationType" CHAR(50),
    "RelationValue" CHAR(36),
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "Configuration_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

you will have more rows, but better performance

You can later pivot this table to better fit other needs.

Comment: I need to run efficient queries against this database so I need the foreign keys in place, that's why I had this many fields in the table with specific keys. I can't dynamically tell postgres which table to join by using a `relationtype` field...or can I?

Comment: You can have covering index on a value from the column which will help to run efficiently at the cost of your table size. but it will allow you to keep only 2 columns, one for the name of the indicator and one for the value saved.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16